Are GLM response residuals supposed to be centered on 0?
I'm struggling with the idea of residuals and error terms in GLMs. I've gathered that there are no explicit error terms in GLMs because the distributions modelled don't allow the decomposition between a predictor and an error term as with the linear model.
However fitted values can still differ from observed values and therefore we can compute residuals from the model. In my mind, regardless of the type of model, you want your fitted values to be close to the observed value and randomly distributed above or below the observed value (you don't want a systematic bias where the fitted value is always above the observed values or a trend in the residuals). That would me, ideally, that the residuals fllow a normal distribution centered on 0 and independent of the predictor value for GLM just like for LM. Therefore, why could we use a classic qq-plot with GLMs as we do with linear models ?
Thanks

Why would a model in which the likelihood is not gaussian be expected to yield residuals which are gaussian?

Think about a Bernoulli model with probabilities close to 0 ore one. Then response residuals would necessary be wery skewed

It's not reasonable to expect the residuals to follow a normal distribution, but it is reasonable to want the mean of the residuals (on the appropriate scale) to be 0. For example in logistic regression if I have 20 points with predicted probability .95, 19 responses at 1 and 1 response at 0 would be the ideal outcome and would have a mean residual of 0

Thanks @ischmidt20 for your answer. I've been reading a bit more and I realize that I was confusing residuals randomly distributed around 0 with residuals following a normal distribution centered on 0. I get I'm still confuse that we don't have expected distributions for residuals in GLM against which we can test the residual's observed distribution like we do with linear models and qq-plots.

@DemetriPananos Thank you for taking the time to answer. To be honest, I have no idea how to connect these two ideas (likelihood and distribution of the residuals) so I can't really do more right now except search the internet to try and understand of these two are connected haha

"we don't have expected distributions for residuals in GLM" Well, we kind of do. As we define the residuals as $y - \hat{y}$, we can "expect" the residuals to follow the distribution of $y$ shifted by whatever $\hat{y}$ is. For example in the bernoulli case, if $\hat{y} = .95$, that means we believe the residuals to be -.95 with probability .05 and .05 with probability .95. (A Bernoulli(.95) shifted to the left by .95.) It is just that these distributions aren't really meaningful so we don't care about them.

Hi @ischmidt20. Your answer makes a lot of sense with the intuition I had. However, just to be sure I understand well. Since $\hat{y}$ changes with each observation, you know the expected distribution of the residuals for each observation but it is very likely different between observations right ? Which is why you can generalize to a single distribution that all residuals would follow like in linear regression is that correct ?

Assuming you meant can't generalize to a single distribution like you would for linear regression, yeah, you're pretty much right. Another example, Poisson. Say $\hat{y_1} = 5.43$. Now our residuals are defined on $\ldots -1.43, -.43, .57, 1.57 \ldots$ But $\hat{y_2} = 3.72$. Residuals would be defined on $\ldots -.72, .28, \ldots$

Yes I meant "can't". Thanks @ischmidt20 it makes much more sense now. :)
